# Foreach Loop Echo First Occurrence Only (First Element Only)

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

I've been trying to select the first occurrence in foreach loop. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($data,true);
foreach($data['screenshots'] as $values){
    echo $values[0];
}
?>
```

It's echoing "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" only.

Here's the JSON Data: pastebin.com/WqyJBAbg

Comment: $values[0] is just showing the first letter, try without the [0]

Comment: If you want first screenshot, use $data['screenshots'][0]. Using foreach iterates every screenshot.

Comment: without [0] it's echoing all the outputs

Comment: $data['screenshots'][0] not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help out.

```
$data = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($data,true);

foreach($data['screenshots'] as $index => $value) {
  if ($index == 0) {
       echo $data['screenshots'][$index];
  }
}
```

Comment: its working but why [0] doesn't echo the first occurrence!

Comment: echo $data['screenshots'][0]; would also work, you were not just accessing it properly